# Access array defined in inline assembler from C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have an integer declared in Assembler, and I use it in C in the following way:

```
asm(
            "number:    \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n
);

extern int number;
int main(){
    //do something with number
}
```

Now I want to declare a 32 byte array in Assembler. I tried the following:

```
asm(
            "number:    \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
);

extern unsigned char* number;
int main() {
    printf("%x ", number[0]); //gives segmentation fault
}
```

I do not really know Assembler, but I have to use for this specific variable.

Comment: Declaration is not enough. You need to **define** it. And: you cannot define an _integer_ in Assembler; Assembler does not have a concept of datatypes. And if that shall be 32 bit data, you do you declare it in your C code as `char`? (And "I have to use ... someone pointing a gun at you?)

Comment: Why did you think `unsigned char *` was right? That doesn't make any sense to me, at all. Perhaps `extern int number[8];` but I'm really out on a limb here.

Comment: If you declare `unsigned char *number`, that means the value at the location `number` represents holds an address or a pointer. In this case, that address or pointer is `0xFFFFFFFF`. Then when you dereference it as `number[0]`, you are attempting to reference whatever is at address `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is invalid. Try `"number: my_array\n"` followed by `"my_array:\n" prefacing your list of `.long` values. Or try the method @unwind suggested.

Comment: Do you want a 32 *byte* value or 32 *bit* value?

Comment: @Linus, 32 byte. Based on unwind's comment I declared it as extern unsigned char number[32].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inline assembler does this

```
asm(
            "number:    \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            [snip rest of array]
);
```

You then tell *C* that *number* is

```
extern unsigned char* number;
```

This says that *number* is a pointer to an unsigned character. Then you access it like this:

```
printf("%x ", number[0]);
```

This says to de-reference the pointer in *number* and return the first character. It would have been the same as doing:

```
printf("%x ", *(number+0));
```

Problem is that *number* was defined as a pointer. Assuming 32-bit pointers that translates to:

```
*(0xFFFFFFFF+0)
```

If you get a segfault it is probably because the address 0xFFFFFFFF is not accessible to your program.

You can change your *extern* statement to read:

```
extern unsigned char number[32];
```

Now *number* is an array of 32 unsigned characters. I'd be inclined to use the `inttypes.h` header and declare it as:

```
extern uint8_t number[32];
```

`uint8_t` is guaranteed to be 8 bits (or 1 byte). `char` on the other hand is defined as being a minimum of 8 bits (but can be more). However `sizeof(char)` will always return 1. I prefer `uint8_t` (unsigned 8 bit integers) just so you know you are dealing with 8 bit values which seems to be the case here. I'd modify the code to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

__asm__(
            "number:    \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFE \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
            ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
);

extern uint8_t number[32];

int main() {
    printf("%x ", number[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that if you intend to compile using GCC as C99 (will work with GCC's C89 as well) it is preferable to use `__asm__` instead of `asm` since GCC's default is to disable the `asm` keyword (unless overridden with `-fasm`) when using `-std=c99` option.

*number* is probably not a good name for an array of unsigned characters. It may cause confusion when someone has to come along and maintain your code.