# Referencing an external msp430 assembly .string in a c extern

Tags: c, assembly, extern, c-strings, msp430

Programming the msp430, I have a string declared using the `.string` directive:

```
message:    .string "Hello World"
```

I want to reference that outside the module, so I `.def`'d it:

```
            .def    message
message:    .string "Hello World"
```

In C, I want to reference the string, but get the wrong character:

```
extern char* message;

int main(void) {
    char c = *message; // First character of message is listed as 'z'
}
```

Any ideas about what might cause this? It compiles fine, and there are several functions in the assembly that I reference without a problem.

Comment: what happens if you do `extern char message[];`

Comment: It is very similar to this x86 question from tonight, for similar reasons. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33521099/3857942

Comment: I searched the site forever. Probably didn't find it because I included msp430 in the search parameters.

Comment: Yeah it was similar, I can understand that you wouldn't have seen it since it was a was a different architecture. Was just pointing it out. Ross's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extern char message[];`.  When you declare it as a pointer you're saying `message` is a value that only takes 2 bytes of memory and stores an address. When declare it as array of `char` you're saying that's a sequence of 1 byte characters, which is what a string is.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that!